# How set proxy for specific urls in ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: server, proxy, tor

I want to set proxy for transmission packet just for specific url like `api.example.com` in ubuntu 20.04 server.

In this case all `curl` requests should pass through proxy.

I prefer to use `Tor`. How it possible?

Comment: Proxy for what application?  There may be a global setting for proxy, but the application is free to use it or ignore it, and complex proxy rules will certainly be application specific.

Comment: @user10489 i need `curl` requests for specific urls pass through `tor` proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `curl` application supports proxy configuration by command line, config file, or environment variable.

All three of these provide similar functionality (command line and config file are actually identical).

Proxy can be controled by protocol (e.g., `http`, `https`, others..) and hosts can be excluded from the proxy, but no method is provided to only proxy a specific host.

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to enable proxy specifically (via command line option) when trying to use curl on that host.

Comment: I want proxy be set permanently on the server for specific urls which calls through cURL, I should go by setting config file or environment variable? Also is there any documentation for it? please share the link to a documentation.

Comment: There is no way to do it only for specific urls.  You can do it for all urls except specific urls instead.  Either config file or environment variable would work.  All the documentation for this is in the `man` page for curl.  Type `man curl` to read it.